# Destroy target of WeakReference

Tags: c#, weak-references, destroy, typedreference

I'm writing a small MemoryManager for my WPF application and reached the following problem.

What i do: I store a lot of instances as a `WeakReference` in a `IList<WeakReference>`. Later, when i want to free all memory, i want to destroy all alive objects in the list.

To do this, i try to get the reference to the object, like this:

```
foreach (WeakReference wr in references)
{
    if (wr.IsAlive == true)
    {
        if(wr.Target != null)
        {
            TypedReference tf = __makeref(wr.Target);
        }
    }
}
```

But i dont't know how to destroy **tf**. I tried to use `__refval`, but it does not work for me.

**Sample**:

```
InstanceDestructManager idm = new InstanceDestructManager();
IList<string> test = new List<string>();
test.Add("123");

idm.AddNullable<IList<string>>(ref test);
idm.Dispose();

// Should not be possible, because after idm.Dispose "test" should be null
test.Add("456");
```

**General code for**:

```
public static void Test(ref object pa)
{
    pa = null;
}
```

Maybe some one has an idea, thank you!

Comment: In .NET, you don't 'destroy' objects. You leave them lingering and let the GC do its job. Your best course is to destroy this 'small MemoryManager' now.

Comment: @HenkHolterman ok, than i will search for a new solution. Because my application memory is increasing very bad and it seems that the GC has some problem with detecting closed Tabs. Or i need to Dispose every thing in the "Close-Tab" event. Thank you!

Comment: Dispose() is about resources, not about memory. Make sure you understand the problem first.

Comment: And how bad is bad? Too many people have wasted far too much time just because some number in Taskmanager was going up.

Comment: Until OutOfMemory exceptions. The application often reach 2GB of ram.

Comment: OK, that is a problem. Now find out why. Look up 'Memory Profiler'.  We can't help you from this, afaik Tabs don't close.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `WeakReference.Target` to `null` will release the reference to it. There is no such thing as destroy memory in C#. The GC collect memory when there are no references to it. And even then it decides on its own when to free them. [GC.Collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) forces this. But this is not for production purposes unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Your solution can't work, because you only set `Target` to null and not what target is referencing.

Comment: The target property is a setter, so yes you can set wnat the target is referencing

Comment: @Sievajat, but i don't want to set what target is referencing, i want to set the already referenced object to null. I want to find a general solution fore the code, under my update: **General code for**

Comment: @BendEg : You can't  _set an object to null_. That just makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe, or improve it. Right now it's asking for help on a wrong solution.